# Newton's method returns NaN

Tags: c++, nan, newtons-method

I wrote  simple recursive version of Newton's method:

```
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double DeriveAt(double (*f)(double), double x){
    return( (f(x+0.001)-f(x-0.001))/0.002 );
};

double FindRoot(double (*f)(double), double x0){
    double corr=f(x0)/DeriveAt(f,x0);
    if(abs(corr) > 1.E-7)
            FindRoot(f, x0-corr);
    else return(x0);
};
```

If I call my function, e.g. `FindRoot(sin, 4)`, `NaN` is returned. I checked the function by printing the value of `x0` after every step, and everything seems to work unitl the last iteration. For some reason, the function calls itself once more than it actually should, probably creating something like `0/0` when calculating the last `corr`.

Comment: You're missing a `return` from your `FindRoot`. Is that the problem?

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something stupid. With `return FindRoot(...)` it works.

Comment: If you're in GCC land, you should make more use of things like `-Wall`, which would have given you _"test.cpp:16: warning: control reaches end of non-void function"_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I change

```
if(abs(corr) > 1.E-7)
        FindRoot(f, x0-corr);
```

to

```
if(abs(corr) > 1.E-7)
        return FindRoot(f, x0-corr);
```

then `FindRoot(sin, 4)` returns something approximating Pi.